# Iterate through dict to compare IP addresses to networks

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries that I am trying to compare and determine if an IP of an interface belongs to a particular network. The issue I am having is that I don't know how to check each individual IP address against multiple ip addresses. When I do my if statement:

```
if ipaddress.ip_address(interface_address) in ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_int_range):
```

It fails to match because the first `interface_address` it pulls is 192.1.1.1 and `ospf_int_range` returns 192.168.100.1. Here is the dict for `ospf_int_range`.

```py
{
    "id": 1,
    "vrf": "test",
    "area": [{"area-id": 0, "authentication": {"message-digest": [None]}}],
    "network": [
        {"ip": "192.1.1.1", "wildcard": "0.0.0.0", "area": 0},
        {"ip": "192.168.100.1", "wildcard": "0.0.0.0", "area": 0},
    ],
    "router-id": "192.1.1.1",
}
```

The variable `interface_address` can also have multiple values depending on the number of configured interfaces in the dict. Ideally, for every interface in the loop, it would compare against all the 'network' 'ip'/'wildcard' pairs in the other dict.

```py
# define variables
device_config = api_get_conf()
routing_protocol = device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['router']

# create filename structure
gettime = date.today()
timestamp = gettime.strftime('%d%b%Y')
hostname = device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['hostname']
report_filename = '%s_%s.csv' % (hostname, timestamp)

def ospf_audit():
    for interface_types in device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['interface']:
        if 'GigabitEthernet' in interface_types:
            for interface_attributes in device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['interface']['GigabitEthernet']:
                if 'vrf' in interface_attributes.keys():
                    interface_names = str(interface_attributes.get('name'))
                    interface_vrfs = str(interface_attributes['vrf']['forwarding'])
                    if 'ip' in interface_attributes.keys():
                        interface_ips = interface_attributes['ip']['address']['primary']['address']
                        for network_statement in routing_protocol['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']['process-id-vrf']:
                            for ospf_network in network_statement['network']:
                                ospf_interfaces = ospf_network['ip']
                                ospf_wildcards = ospf_network['wildcard']
                                wildcard_to_mask = str(ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_interfaces+'/'+ospf_wildcards, strict=False).netmask)
                                if wildcard_to_mask == '0.0.0.0':
                                    wildcard_to_mask = '255.255.255.255'
                            ospf_intf_range = ipaddress.ip_interface(ospf_interfaces+'/'+wildcard_to_mask)
                            print(network_statement)
                            print(interface_ips,ospf_intf_range)
                            if ipaddress.ip_address(interface_ips) in ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_intf_range):
                                if 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf' in interface_attributes['ip']:
                                    if 'message-digest-key' in interface_attributes['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']:
                                        interface_ospf_auth = interface_attributes['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']['message-digest-key'][0]['md5']
                                        if 'auth-key' in interface_ospf_auth:
                                            print(interface_names) 
                                            print('OSPF enabled and configured with MD5 authentication.')
                                        else:
                                            print('Opps something happened...')
                                    else:
                                        print(interface_names)
                                        print('OSPF enabled and configured without MD5 authentication.')
                                else:
                                    print(interface_names) 
                                    print('OSPF enabled and configured without MD5 authentication.')  
                            else:
                                print(interface_names) 
                                print('No OSPF configuration under interface.')

                    else:
                        print('\nGigabitEthernet '+interface_names+' vrf: '+interface_vrfs+' IP Address: Shutdown')
                elif interface_attributes.get('vrf') is None:
                    interface_names = str(interface_attributes.get('name'))
                    if 'ip' in interface_attributes.keys():
                        interface_ips = interface_attributes['ip']['address']['primary']['address']
                        for network_statement in routing_protocol['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']['process-id']:
                            for ospf_network in network_statement['network']:
                                ospf_interfaces = ospf_network['ip']
                                ospf_wildcards = ospf_network['wildcard']
                                wildcard_to_mask = str(ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_interfaces+'/'+ospf_wildcards, strict=False).netmask)
                                if wildcard_to_mask == '0.0.0.0':
                                    wildcard_to_mask = '255.255.255.255'
                            ospf_intf_range = ipaddress.ip_interface(ospf_interfaces+'/'+wildcard_to_mask)
                            print(network_statement)
                            print(interface_ips,ospf_intf_range)
                            if ipaddress.ip_address(interface_ips) in ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_intf_range):
                                if 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf' in interface_attributes['ip']:
                                    if 'message-digest-key' in interface_attributes['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']:
                                        interface_ospf_auth = interface_attributes['ip']['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']['message-digest-key'][0]['md5']
                                        if 'auth-key' in interface_ospf_auth:
                                            print(interface_names) 
                                            print('OSPF enabled and configured with MD5 authentication.')
                                        else:
                                            print('Opps something happened...')
                                    else:
                                        print(interface_names)
                                        print('OSPF enabled and configured without MD5 authentication.')
                                else:
                                    print(interface_names) 
                                    print('OSPF enabled and configured without MD5 authentication.')  
                            else:
                                print(interface_names) 
                                print('No OSPF configuration under interface.')
                    else:
                        print('\nGigabitEthernet '+interface_names+' vrf: global IP Address: Shutdown')

        elif 'Loopback' in interface_types:
            for interface_attributes in device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['interface']['Loopback']:
                if 'vrf' in interface_attributes.keys():
                    interface_names = str(interface_attributes.get('name'))
                    interface_vrfs = str(interface_attributes['vrf']['forwarding'])
                    if 'ip' in interface_attributes.keys():
                        interface_ips = interface_attributes['ip']['address']['primary']['address']
                        for network_statement in routing_protocol['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']['process-id-vrf']:
                            for ospf_network in network_statement['network']:
                                ospf_interfaces = ospf_network['ip']
                                ospf_wildcards = ospf_network['wildcard']
                                wildcard_to_mask = str(ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_interfaces+'/'+ospf_wildcards, strict=False).netmask)
                                if wildcard_to_mask == '0.0.0.0':
                                    wildcard_to_mask = '255.255.255.255'
                            ospf_intf_range = ipaddress.ip_interface(ospf_interfaces+'/'+wildcard_to_mask)
                            print(network_statement)
                            print(interface_ips,ospf_intf_range)
                            if ipaddress.ip_address(interface_ips) in ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_intf_range):
                                print(interface_names) 
                                print('OSPF configuration under interface.')  
                            else:
                                print(interface_names) 
                                print('No OSPF configuration under interface.')
                    else:
                        print('\nLoopback '+interface_names+' vrf: '+interface_vrfs+' IP Address: Shutdown')
                elif interface_attributes.get('vrf') is None:
                    interface_names = str(interface_attributes.get('name'))
                    if 'ip' in interface_attributes.keys():
                        interface_ips = interface_attributes['ip']['address']['primary']['address']
                        for network_statement in routing_protocol['Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf']['ospf']['process-id']:
                            for ospf_network in network_statement['network']:
                                ospf_interfaces = ospf_network['ip']
                                ospf_wildcards = ospf_network['wildcard']
                                wildcard_to_mask = str(ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_interfaces+'/'+ospf_wildcards, strict=False).netmask)
                                if wildcard_to_mask == '0.0.0.0':
                                    wildcard_to_mask = '255.255.255.255'
                            ospf_intf_range = ipaddress.ip_interface(ospf_interfaces+'/'+wildcard_to_mask)
                            print(network_statement)
                            print(interface_ips,ospf_intf_range)
                            if ipaddress.ip_address(interface_ips) in ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_intf_range):
                                print(interface_names) 
                                print('OSPF configuration under interface.')  
                            else:
                                print(interface_names) 
                                print('No OSPF configuration under interface.')
                    else:
                        print('\nLoopback '+interface_names+' vrf: global IP Address: Shutdown')
```

You can see in the output below, the interfaces below have networks in the dictionary to match the interface, but it pulls a network to compare with and then doesn't iterate through them.

{'id': 1, 'vrf': 'test', 'area': [{'area-id': 0, 'authentication': {'message-digest': [None]}}], 'network': [{'**ip': '192.1.1.1**', 'wildcard': '0.0.0.0', 'area': 0}, {'**ip': '192.168.100.1**', 'wildcard': '0.0.0.0', 'area': 0}], 'router-id': '192.1.1.1'}

In this case the IP address from the interface is 192.168.1.1 and it fails the if condition by matching on the network 192.168.100.1/32.

192.1.1.1 192.168.100.1/32

0
No OSPF configuration under interface.

{'id': 2, 'area': [{'area-id': 0, 'authentication': {'message-digest': [None]}}], 'network': [{'ip': '192.2.2.1', 'wildcard': '0.0.0.0', 'area': 0}, {'ip': '192.168.200.0', 'wildcard': '0.0.0.255', 'area': 0}]}

192.2.2.1 192.168.200.0/24
1
No OSPF configuration under interface.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you condense your problem to a set of inputs and expected outputs? 192.1.1.1 is not in  192.168.100.1/32 so that's expected?

Comment: I agree, but what I want is for it continue to the next network and match against that. I just can't get the networks to loop.